# Is there an easy way to add missing dependencies in a Fuse Project?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

The console management application reports missing imported packages after installing my bundle.
[console printscreen showing missing packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEjU3.png)

Does anyone know a step by step process to add these dependencies to my project?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These are just optional imports, and are not needed. And no its not super easy to install as you would need to know which feature/bundle to install.

Comment: Actually, these dependencies appear Optional because I put the "resolution:=optional" statement in the POM. Problem is that when I try to Start the package I get the "Unresolved constraint in bundle" error. So I need to install these dependencies anyway...The automatic installation when adding to the POM is the only chance we have to achieve this, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. To resolve missing dependencies in Management console type this (e.g., if you're missing `camel-sql`):

```
features:list | grep sql
```

Then type the following:

```
features:install camel-sql
```

Camel SQL dependency and its derived dependencies will be installed in your Fuse instance.

Comment: Or you may just configure it on your profile. Please take a look at this theme. May be a better option for deployment in your scenario.